# Get 2 latest records and do a math function

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have a table called `Ronde`:

```
 ID  | Teamid | Timestamp
----------------------------------------
 1   |   1    | 2013-06-28 18:35:28
 2   |   1    | 2013-06-28 18:36:28
 3   |   2    | 2013-06-28 18:36:30
 4   |   3    | 2013-06-28 18:37:28
 5   |   2    | 2013-06-28 18:40:28
 6   |   1    | 2013-06-28 18:42:28
 7   |   2    | 2013-06-28 18:43:28
 8   |   3    | 2013-06-28 18:48:28
```

[Here's a sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2dc3f) of same.

So what i need is a query who takes the 2 newest records grouped by `Teamid` and do a math function with `timestamp`.

So example:

```
newest1, newest2    
result =  ( 60 minutes / (newest2.timestamp - newest1.timestamp) ) * 6
```

The result is the avg speed between 2 timestamps.

```
`LIMIT` in subquery don't work
```

Someone have a solution for my problem ???

Desired output data :

```
Teamid  |  Speed
1 | 60
2 | 120
3 | 32,72
```

Comment: Show desired output based on your sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this....

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2dc3f/7

?

Comment: your example works , but if i use my db with 20 teamid's and 120 records it's return only 4 results

Comment: It works :-) for the testing purpose i add mass records with same timestamp and then it don't , but with different timestamps it works perfect